# Insert RatingBar in MvxDialogActrivity

Tags: mvvmcross

I want to insert a ratingBar in MvxDialogActivity.When user click on a specific item in a listView,I want to display details of clicked item and ratingBar and some buttons on a dialog.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [n=32 mvvmcross](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6fNXGErr9to) tutorial shows you how to create a bindable dialog activity.I shouldn't take much effort to add a rating bar into it.